# SQL in syntax comparison in proper order

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding this statement:

```
select * 
from texts 
where id in (1, 3) 
  and address in ('address_one', 'address_another');
```

I want to have all records which fulfill these conditions:

- has id = 1 and has address 'address_one'
- has id = 3 and has address 'address_another'

if there is any way of doing this ?

Comment: the all thing is to make it in shorter form than e.q. (id = 1 and address = 'address_one') or (id = 3 and address = 'address_other')  - that isn't answer good enough.

Comment: The obvious question: *WHY?*  As in, Why do you need it to be shorter than that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to re-write the WHERE clause as follows;

```
(id = 1 and address = 'address_one') or (id = 3 and address = 'address_other')
```

An alternative approach could be;

```
(cast(id as varchar(32)) + '_' + address) in ('1_address_one', '3_address_other')
```

Comment: the all thing is to make it in shorter form that you proposed. I read about decode (which impose ordering in "in syntax" statement) and i am looking something similar but to my case.